# Python compiler and constants defined inside a function

Tags: python, performance, compiler-optimization

Does the Python compiler recognize constants defined within a function, such that it only computes their values once regardless of how many times the function is subsequently called in the code?

For example,

```
def f():
    x = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
    # stuff

for i in range( 100 ):
    f()
```

Would `x` be recalculated the 100 times `f()` is called?

It is not always possible to define constants outside the function that uses them, and I'm curious if Python has got your back in these situations.

Comment: Nothing is constant in Python... It is a hyperdynamic language. Even functions, classes and modules can later be patched.

Comment: How would you define `x` as a constant in python? How would the compiler know that `x` isn't going to change (in your `#stuff` section for example)?

Comment: [Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) ... [Naming and Binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Note that this applies to CPython, and may be different in other implementations)

Python code is parsed and compiled into bytecode. You can see the instructions used with the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module.

```
>>> def f(x):
...     x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              6 LOAD_CONST               4 (4)
              8 BUILD_LIST               4
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

>>> print(dis.Bytecode(f).info())
Name:              f
Filename:          <stdin>
Argument count:    1
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  1
Stack size:        4
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, NOFREE
Constants:
   0: None
   1: 1
   2: 2
   3: 3
   4: 4
Variable names:
   0: x
```

As you can see, integer literals are constants, but lists have to be built everytime.

This is a relatively fast operation (Probably even quicker than looking up a global, but the time is still negligible)

If you had a function `g` that used a tuple instead, it is loaded as a constant:

```
>>> def g(x):
...     x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               5 ((1, 2, 3, 4))
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> print(dis.Bytecode(g).info())
Name:              g
Filename:          <stdin>
Argument count:    1
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  1
Stack size:        4
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, NOFREE
Constants:
   0: None
   1: 1
   2: 2
   3: 3
   4: 4
   5: (1, 2, 3, 4)
Variable names:
   0: x
```

But this seems like a case of premature optimisation.

The constants stored for a function can be found as `function.__code__.co_consts`.

```
>>> g.__code__.co_consts
(None, 1, 2, 3, 4, (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

---

The reason a new list has to be built every time is so that if the list is changed, it won't affect a list that is loaded everytime.

And the tuple optimisation goes away if it isn't a list of constants.

```
>>> def h(x):
...     x = (1, 2, 3, x)
>>> dis.dis(h)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              8 BUILD_TUPLE              4
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
>>> print(dis.Bytecode(h).info())
Name:              h
Filename:          <stdin>
Argument count:    1
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  1
Stack size:        4
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, NOFREE
Constants:
   0: None
   1: 1
   2: 2
   3: 3
Variable names:
   0: x
```

Comment: Note: Also as an implementation detail, `list`s of constants that are used in a manner that precludes mutation (directly iterated or containment checked without assigning to a named variable, e.g. `for x in [1,2,3]:` or `if x in [1,2,3]:`) are compile-time constants; the peephole optimizer replaces them with `tuple` constants (since, when it's impossible to mutate them and they're used in a few known patterns, a `list` and `tuple` behave identically, but the `tuple` is slightly more efficient to store and constant, making it safe).

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**: for **lists**, it **does not**.

If we check the intermediate code after compilation with `dis`, we see:

```
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              9 LOAD_CONST               4 (4)
             12 BUILD_LIST               4
             15 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

So as you can see the program first loads constants `1` to `4` and pushes these on the stack, and the constructs a list with these constants, so that means it constructs a list **each time**.

In case the **list is not mutated**, I propose to **define the constant outside the function**:

```
some_constant = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def f():
    # use some_constant
    # ...
    pass
```

Comment: If it's not mutated, and you're not relying on a few `list` specific behaviors (e.g. equality comparison with another `list`), using a `tuple` of constant literals within the function would be faster and avoid scoping issues (avoids some other function/module messing with it by accident), since it can be stored fully constructed in the function's constant table. Each use becomes a simple `LOAD_CONST` (using the literal directly) or `LOAD_FAST` (if in a named local) which boil down to C array lookups, rather than a `LOAD_GLOBAL`, which is (at least) one `dict` lookup.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I know that, but a tuple is not a list and vice versa. If you later pass this list to a function that checks `isinstance(x, list)`, then for a list, it will fail. So we can not assume that it will have completely identical behavior.

Comment: True, but 1. A function that's doing strict type checking like that is usually bad form and 2. The cases where it's not bad form are typically cases where it's mutating the `list`, so the global wouldn't be safe. You'd need to copy the global on entering the function (`x = some_constant[:]`) to avoid that risk. Fun alternative: Python 3.5's unpacking generalizations let you have your cake and eat it too. You could do `x = [*(1, 2, 3, 4)]`, which constructs the `list` by loading the constant `tuple`, then performing a single byte code `BUILD_LIST_UNPACK`.

Comment: The generalized unpacking technique, for a four element `tuple`->`list` is no real improvement on the `list` literal, but for larger sequences unpacking is faster. They're both faster than slicing a global `list` to get a shallow copy for any reasonable size `list` (the slicing approach takes over 33% longer for four elements; slices are weirdly expensive here).